# Make Calculator For big numbers with string input and output and Processes in functions

Tags: python, arrays, string, tkinter, lambda

So I am trying to make a calculator with python and tkinter
and I have to use only 2 operator (+ and -) and make other operators (like * and /) with them.
I tried that without string and that's not worked for very big numbers, I have to do that with string
I am not allowed to use  ready-made libraries in python language.
I have no idea how to do that with string
pls help me

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Calculator !")
root.geometry('800x700')

e = Entry(root, width=32, borderwidth=5, font=('helvetica', 32))
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)


# Calc Functions!

def sum(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2


def minus(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2


def multiply(num1, num2):
    x = 0
    if (num2 < num1):
        num1 = num1 + num2
        num2 = num1 - num2
        num1 = num1 - num2
    for i in range(0, num2):
        x = x + num1
    return x


def button_click(number):
    current = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, str(current) + str(number))


def button_clear():
    e.delete(0, END)


def button_add():
    first_number = e.get()
    global f_num
    global math
    math = "addition"
    f_num = int(first_number)
    e.delete(0, END)


def button_subtract():
    first_number = e.get()
    global f_num
    global math
    math = "subtraction"
    f_num = int(first_number)
    e.delete(0, END)


def button_multiply():
    first_number = e.get()
    global f_num
    global math
    math = "multiplication"
    f_num = int(first_number)
    e.delete(0, END)


def button_divide():
    first_number = e.get()
    global f_num
    global math
    math = "division"
    f_num = int(first_number)
    e.delete(0, END)


def button_equal():
    second_number = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)

    if math == "addition":
        e.insert(0, f_num + int(second_number))

    if math == "subtraction":
        e.insert(0, f_num - int(second_number))

    if math == "multiplication":
        e.insert(0, multiply(f_num, int(second_number)))

    if math == "division":
        e.insert(0, f_num / int(second_number))


# Define Buttons

button_1 = Button(root, text="1", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(1))
button_2 = Button(root, text="2", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(2))
button_3 = Button(root, text="3", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(3))
button_4 = Button(root, text="4", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(4))
button_5 = Button(root, text="5", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(5))
button_6 = Button(root, text="6", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(6))
button_7 = Button(root, text="7", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(7))
button_8 = Button(root, text="8", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(8))
button_9 = Button(root, text="9", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(9))
button_0 = Button(root, text="0", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(0))
button_add = Button(root, text="+", padx=39, pady=20, command=button_add)
button_equal = Button(root, text="=", padx=91, pady=20, command=button_equal)
button_clear = Button(root, text="Clear", padx=79, pady=20, command=button_clear)

button_subtract = Button(root, text="-", padx=41, pady=20, command=button_subtract)
button_multiply = Button(root, text="*", padx=40, pady=20, command=button_multiply)
button_divide = Button(root, text="/", padx=41, pady=20, command=button_divide)

# Put the buttons on the screen

button_1.grid(row=4, column=0)
button_2.grid(row=4, column=1)
button_3.grid(row=4, column=2)

button_4.grid(row=3, column=0)
button_5.grid(row=3, column=1)
button_6.grid(row=3, column=2)

button_7.grid(row=2, column=0)
button_8.grid(row=2, column=1)
button_9.grid(row=2, column=2)

button_0.grid(row=4, column=0)
button_clear.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)
button_add.grid(row=5, column=0)
button_equal.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=2)

button_subtract.grid(row=6, column=0)
button_multiply.grid(row=6, column=1)
button_divide.grid(row=1, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You know that `button_1` and `button_0` overlap?

Comment: `result = eval(yourString)`

Comment: @TheLizzard yes that's not my problem this program not complete yet, and not organized

Comment: @MichaelGuidry I knew about this, but I have to do that without this kind of codes as I said

Comment: @FRDLian you know that tkinter is a pre built library and you are using `int` which is part of the same library as `eval`

Comment: @FRDLian ~ There's a difference between 'ready made' libraries and built-in core functionality. What you are implying is that your teacher expects you to build a math parser from scratch. I've done that already, and I say with great confidence that you aren't going to do that. No offense, but your skill level is definitely not there yet. Here's a link to a basic calculator I made as an answer to another one of these calculator question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63382530/10292330 ~ maybe something in there will help you.