# Calculator tkinter to make the number float

Tags: python, tkinter

The function is called `float_number()` and I would like to make that number float for example if I write first number (5) and press `(.)` and add another number like e.g. `(5.2)`- to make that as a float and when I add second number as a float or can be integer to calculate that like on calculator. I tried to get the first number at to insert to that number `(.)` and next to that I am stuck.

```
   from tkinter import *
    from math import *
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Calculator")
    e = Entry(root,width=25,borderwidth=30)
    e.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=15,columnspan=3)
    #BUTTONS
    def button_click(number):
        current = e.get()
        e.delete(0,END)
        e.insert(0,str(current) + str(number))
    def button_clear():
        e.delete(0,END)
    def button_clear_one_char():
        e.delete(len(e.get())-1)
    def button_addition():
        global first_number
        global dividor 
        dividor = "addition"
        first_number = e.get()
        e.delete(0,END)
        first_number = int(first_number)
    def button_substraction():
        global first_number
        global dividor 
        dividor = "substract"
        first_number = e.get()
        first_number = int(first_number)
        e.delete(0,END)
    def button_multiplication():
        global first_number 
        global dividor 
        dividor = "multiply"
        first_number = e.get()
        first_number = int(first_number)
        e.delete(0,END)
    def button_division():
        global first_number 
        global dividor 
        dividor = "division"
        first_number = e.get()
        first_number = int(first_number)
        e.delete(0,END)
     
    
    
    def button_root_number():
        number = e.get()
        number = float(number)
        e.insert(0,number **0.5)
    
    
    def button_equal():
        global first_number 
        global dividor
        global second_number
        second_number = e.get()
        e.delete(0,END)
    
        if dividor == "addition":
            e.insert(0,first_number + int(second_number))
        if dividor == "substract":
            e.insert(0,first_number - int(second_number))
        if dividor == "multiply":
            e.insert(0,first_number * int(second_number))
        if dividor == "division":
            e.insert(0,first_number / int(second_number))
        if dividor == 'float':
            first_float = float(first_number)
            second_float = float(second_number)
            e.insert(0,first_float + second_float) 
    
            
    def float_number():
        global first_number
        first_number = e.get()
        e.delete(0,END)
        e.insert(0,first_number + ".")
    
    
    button_9 = Button(root,text="9",padx=49,pady=20, command=lambda:button_click(9))
    button_8 = Button(root,text="8",padx=49,pady=20, command=lambda:button_click(8))
    button_7 = Button(root,text="7",padx=49,pady=20, command=lambda:button_click(7))
    button_6 = Button(root,text="6",padx=49,pady=20, command=lambda:button_click(6))
    button_5 = Button(root,text="5",padx=49,pady=20, command=lambda:button_click(5))
    button_4 = Button(root,text="4",padx=49,pady=20, command=lambda:button_click(4))
    button_3 = Button(root,text="3",padx=49,pady=20, command=lambda:button_click(3))
    button_2 = Button(root,text="2",padx=49,pady=20, command=lambda:button_click(2))
    button_1 = Button(root,text="1",padx=49,pady=20, command=lambda:button_click(1))
    button_0 = Button(root,text="0",padx=49,pady=20, command=lambda:button_click(0))
    button_cl = Button(root,text="Clear",padx=39,pady=20,command=button_clear)
    button_addi = Button(root,text="+",padx=49,pady=20,command=button_addition)
    button_substr = Button(root,text="-",padx=49,pady=20,command=button_substraction)
    button_eq = Button(root,text="=",padx=49,pady=20,command=button_equal)
    button_multiply = Button(root,text="*",padx=49,pady=20,command=button_multiplication)
    button_divi = Button(root,text="%",padx=49,pady=20,command=button_division)
    button_point = Button(root,text=".",padx=49,pady=20,command=float_number)
    button_clear_2 = Button(root,text="←",padx=49,pady=20,command=button_clear_one_char)
    button_root = Button(root,text="√",padx=49,pady=20,command=lambda:button_root_number())
    
    
    #first three
    button_cl.grid(row=1,column=0)
    button_eq.grid(row=1,column=1)
    button_clear_2.grid(row=1,column=2)
    button_addi.grid(row=1,column=3)
    #second three
    button_7.grid(row=2,column=0)
    button_8.grid(row=2,column=1)
    button_9.grid(row=2,column=2)
    button_substr.grid(row=2,column=3)
    #third three
    button_4.grid(row=3,column=0)
    button_5.grid(row=3,column=1)
    button_6.grid(row=3,column=2)
    button_multiply.grid(row=3,column=3)
    #fourth three
    button_3.grid(row=4,column=0)
    button_2.grid(row=4,column=1)
    button_1.grid(row=4,column=2)
    button_divi.grid(row=4,column=3)
    #FIFTH THREE
    button_0.grid(row=5,column=0)
    button_point.grid(row=5,column=1)
    button_root.grid(row=5,column=2)
    
    
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Change all the places where you use `int()` to use `float()`.

Comment: Yea , i tried that but should i delete the point Button , button_point?

Comment: No, how else will you add a `.` to the number?

Comment: I answered a question with a completely working calculator. It probably has all of the answers you need. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63382530/10292330 . It's in the second code block.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] that doesn't have quite so much code. You've posted a lot of code that isn't strictly necessary to reproduce this problem.

Comment: You actually have a much bigger problem. Type this in your calculator "8+6-3=". You literally need to start over. Your logic for storing operations will only ever store the last one, and that's never going to work. While you are starting completely over from scratch, go look at my example to see a MUCH better way to make your buttons. My entire calculator is shorter than your button instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

> example if I write first number (5) and press (.) and add another
> number like e.g. (5.2)- to make that as a float and when I add second
> number as a float or can be integer to calculate that like on
> calculator.

Don't use wildcard `from tkinter import *`

Use `import tkinter as tk`. The do prefix `tk.` for Every widgets.

You don't need `import math` module.

- Use `StringVar()`. It helps you manage the value of a widget such as
  a `Entry` more effectively.
- Remove  function such as `button_addition`, `button_substraction`,
  `button_multiplication`, `button_division`, `button_root_number` and
  `float_number`.
- Create `button_equal` function.
- Create `button_clear` function.
- Create `button_clear_one_char` function.
- Add constant for font `arial = "Arial 12 bold"` keyword for
  `Buttons`.
- In `button_divi = tk.Button(root, ...., command=lambda:button_click('/')`
- In `button_root = tk.Button(root,.... command=lambda:button_click('**')`

Snippet re-wrote:

```
import tkinter as tk
 

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Calculator")

equation = tk.StringVar()
expression = ""

e = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=equation, width=25, borderwidth=30)
e.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=15,columnspan=3)

#BUTTONS
def button_click(number):
    global expression
    expression = expression + str(number)
    equation.set(expression)
    print(number)
    return number

def button_equal():
    try:
        global expression
        global total
 
        total = str(eval(expression)) 
        equation.set(total) 
        expression = ""
 
    except:
        #equation.set(total) 
        equation.set(" error ")
        expression = "" 
     
def button_clear():
    global expression
    expression = ""
    equation.set("")

def button_clear_one_char():
    current = e.get()
    lenght = len(current)-1
    e.delete(lenght, tk.END)

 
arial = "Arial 12 bold"

button_9 = tk.Button(root, text="9", font = arial, highlightbackground='#737373', padx=49,pady=20, command=lambda:button_click('9'))
button_8 = tk.Button(root, text="8", font = arial, highlightbackground='#737373', padx=49,pady=20, command=lambda:button_click('8'))
button_7 = tk.Button(root, text="7", font = arial, highlightbackground='#737373', padx=49,pady=20, command=lambda:button_click('7'))
button_6 = tk.Button(root, text="6", font = arial, highlightbackground='#737373', padx=49,pady=20, command=lambda:button_click('6'))
button_5 = tk.Button(root, text="5", font = arial, highlightbackground='#737373', padx=49,pady=20, command=lambda:button_click('5'))
button_4 = tk.Button(root, text="4", font = arial, highlightbackground='#737373', padx=49,pady=20, command=lambda:button_click('4'))
button_3 = tk.Button(root, text="3", font = arial, highlightbackground='#737373', padx=49,pady=20, command=lambda:button_click('3'))
button_2 = tk.Button(root, text="2", font = arial, highlightbackground='#737373', padx=49,pady=20, command=lambda:button_click('2'))
button_1 = tk.Button(root, text="1", font = arial, highlightbackground='#737373', padx=49,pady=20, command=lambda:button_click('1'))
button_0 = tk.Button(root, text="0", font = arial, highlightbackground='#737373', padx=49,pady=20, command=lambda:button_click('0'))
button_cl = tk.Button(root, text="Clear", padx=39, pady=20, command=button_clear)
button_addi = tk.Button(root, text="+", font = arial, highlightbackground='#737373', padx=39, pady=20, command=lambda:button_click('+'))
button_substr = tk.Button(root, text="-", font = arial, highlightbackground='#737373', padx=49, pady=20, command=lambda:button_click('-'))
button_eq = tk.Button(root, text="=", font = arial, highlightbackground='#737373', padx=49, pady=20, command=button_equal)
button_multiply = tk.Button(root, text="*", font = arial, highlightbackground='#737373', padx=49, pady=20, command=lambda:button_click('*'))
button_divi = tk.Button(root, text="/", font = arial, highlightbackground='#737373', padx=49, pady=20, command=lambda:button_click('/'))
button_point = tk.Button(root, text=".", font = arial, highlightbackground='#737373', padx=49, pady=20, command=lambda:button_click('.'))
button_clear_2 = tk.Button(root, text="←", font = arial, highlightbackground='#737373', padx=49, pady=20,command=button_clear_one_char)
button_root = tk.Button(root, text="^", font = arial, highlightbackground='#737373', padx=49, pady=20,command=lambda:button_click('**'))


#first three
button_cl.grid(row=1,column=0)
button_eq.grid(row=1,column=1)
button_clear_2.grid(row=1,column=2)
button_addi.grid(row=1,column=3)
#second three
button_7.grid(row=2,column=0)
button_8.grid(row=2,column=1)
button_9.grid(row=2,column=2)
button_substr.grid(row=2,column=3)
#third three
button_4.grid(row=3,column=0)
button_5.grid(row=3,column=1)
button_6.grid(row=3,column=2)
button_multiply.grid(row=3,column=3)
#fourth three
button_3.grid(row=4,column=0)
button_2.grid(row=4,column=1)
button_1.grid(row=4,column=2)
button_divi.grid(row=4,column=3)
#FIFTH THREE
button_0.grid(row=5,column=0)
button_point.grid(row=5,column=1)
button_root.grid(row=5,column=2)


root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]